Single Surface Patch That Covers the Hyperboloid of One Sheet
I am aware that there are very similar questions here and here. However, neither of these have any answers that convince me of what I need to know. So, the question:

Fix $\theta \in [0,\pi)$. Let $L_{\theta} = \left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | \begin{pmatrix}(x-z)\cos\theta - (1-y)\sin\theta \\ (x+z)\sin\theta - (1+y)\cos\theta\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right\}$, and let $\mathcal{H} = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2 + y^2 - z^2 = 1\}$.
i) Show that $L_{\theta}$ is a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
ii) Use the Regular Value Theorem to show that $\mathcal{H}$ is a surface.
iii) Show that $L_{\theta} \subset \mathcal{H}$ and show that every point in $\mathcal{H}$ is on $L_{\theta}$ for some $\theta \in [0,\pi)$.
iv) Find a single surface patch that covers the whole of $\mathcal{H}.$

I have done parts i - iii. I am now trying to answer part iv and struggling. From looking around I believe that it's $L_{\theta}$ that is supposed to be this single surface patch (?).
However, I don't know how to express this in the explicit form that we have been using in my course, which I understand. That is, a map $\sigma : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ is a surface patch if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open set, $\sigma$ is injective and continuous.
In part i) of the question I obtained the following representation of $L_{\theta}$:
$$
L_{\theta} = \begin{cases} \begin{pmatrix}x \\ -1 \\ x\end{pmatrix}& \text{if } \theta = 0 \\ 
                           \begin{pmatrix}x \\ 1 \\ -x\end{pmatrix}& \text{if } \theta = \pi / 2 \\
                           \begin{pmatrix}1/2[(1+y)\text{cot}\theta + (1-y)\tan \theta] \\ y \\ 1/2[(1+y)\text{cot}\theta - (1-y)\tan \theta]\end{pmatrix}& \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
So, my thought was to define this surface patch that covers $\mathcal{H}$ by $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$$
\sigma(u,v) = \begin{cases} \begin{pmatrix}u \\ -1 \\ u\end{pmatrix}& \text{if } u = 0 \\ 
                           \begin{pmatrix}u \\ 1 \\ -u\end{pmatrix}& \text{if } u = \pi / 2 \\
                           \begin{pmatrix}1/2[(1+v)\text{cot}(u) + (1-v)\tan(u)] \\ v \\ 1/2[(1+v)\text{cot}(u) - (1-v)\tan(u)]\end{pmatrix}& \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
My only issue is that the linked posts above don't seem to show anything like this, and I can't find anything else similar. I'm just unsure if I've interpreted everything correctly and whether this $\sigma$ is indeed a surface patch that covers $\mathcal{H}$?

It covers the surface and is smooth; the only issue remaining is whether your book accepts non-injective mapping as a surface patch. Since they say $ 0 \leq \theta < 2 \pi $  I would guess so. What book?

A hint: Because the hyperboloid of one sheet is homeomorphic to a cylinder (not to a rectangle or disk), a single-patch coordinate system needs to be defined on

 some plane region homeomorphic to an annulus, such as the punctured plane.

Another hint just in case:

 On the punctured $(u, v)$-plane, the mapping $$(u, v) \mapsto (x, y, z) = \biggl(\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^{2} + v^{2}}}, \frac{v}{\sqrt{u^{2} + v^{2}}}, \log(u^{2} + v^{2})\biggr)$$is a single patch covering the unit cylinder. (This claim requires straightforward checking.) There are multiple ways to compose this with another mapping to get the hyperboloid of one sheet, such as projecting away from the $z$-axis, or using hyperbolic functions; I omit this detail in case you have a favorite.

